# Проблема с получением нужного результата по запросу

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

есть 2 таблицы (*CROSS_T* и *PLAN_D*) (см. рис.)[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и сводная view по договорам.
У меня не получается из этих двух таблиц получить результирующую, а именно:
получить все уникальные "*CONTRACT_ID*" из "*CROSS_T*" с номерами договоров "*NUMBER_CONTRACT*" из "*PLAN_D*" по полю "*PROPOSAL_ID*".
Т.е.
В "*CROSS_T*" есть разные значения "*CONTRACT_ID*", все они имеют объединение полем "*PROPOSAL_ID*".
**1)** В результате должен быть результат из 2 полей (*ID* договора и его номер).

```
"CONTRACT_ID" "NUMBER_CONTRACT"  
    45           123/15-19 
    47           бп1/47-19  
    48           бп1/47-19  
    49           бп1/47-19 
    50           бп1/47-19
```

**2)** есть еще сводная *view* по договорам

```
AS
select
c.ID, ct.CLIENT_ID, cl.NAME_ORGANIZATION_FULL as NAME_ORGANIZATION_FULL, cl.TYPE_NP || cl.CITY as NP,
list(distinct(sw.NAME_SORT_WORK), ', ') as LIST_SORT_WORK,
count(distinct(sw.NAME_SORT_WORK)) as COUNT_SORT_WORK,
list(distinct(dp.NAME_SHORT), ', ') as LIST_DEPARTMENT_EXECUTE,
count(distinct(n.DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE)) as COUNT_DEPARTMENT_EXECUTE,
list(distinct(p.NUMBER_IN), ', ') as LIST_PROPOSAL_NUMBER_IN,
list(distinct(p.ID), ', ') as LIST_PROPOSAL_ID
from CONTRACT c
  join CROSS_T ct on ct.CONTRACT_ID = c.ID
  join CLIENT cl on ct.CLIENT_ID = cl.ID
  left join NC n on n.CONTRACT_ID = c.ID
  left join DEVICES d on n.DEVICE_ID = d.ID
  left join SORT_WORK sw on d.SORT_WORK_ID = sw.ID
  left join DEPARTMENT dp on dp.ID = n.DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE
  left join PROPOSAL p on p.ID = ct.PROPOSAL_ID
group by c.ID, ct.CLIENT_ID, cl.NAME_ORGANIZATION_FULL, cl.TYPE_NP, cl.CITY
;
```

Не плохо было бы результат первого вопроса (2 поля) подключить к этой view (где "*CONTRACT_ID*" (из первого вопроса) = "*с.ID*" (из второго вопроса)).
P.S. Эта view также имеет "*join CROSS_T* "

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 1) Замените фотографии на CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO. 2) Объясните подробнее цепь соответствия (например, как получена последняя строка `50 - 'бп1/47-19'`?). 3) Не задавайте два вопроса в одной теме.

Comment: @Akina, 1) я заменил сделал 3 файла с таблицами и данными и положил на dropbox по ссылке https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ktaxfxkgk9qmjcp/AABIQMV_2-CspUVa_FQlfGK5a?dl=0,

Comment: 2) **50 - 'бп1/47-19' ** эти данные нужно получить: "50" - относится к заявке с "PROPOSAL_ID = 36", к ней же относится и "CONTRACT_ID = 47" (табл. "CROSS_T"). А в табл. "PLAN_D" там где "CONTRACT_ID = 47" поле ""NUMBER_CONTRACT"=бп1/47-19". Таким образом у контрактов с ID = 47, 48, 49, 50 будет одинаковый номер 'бп1/47-19'

Comment: 3) второй вопрос тесно связан с первым, и я посчитал, что легче отвечающим будет, эти вопросы не разделять

Comment: *сделал 3 файла с таблицами и данными и положил на dropbox* Нафига они там нужны? Причешите до совместимого состояния и создайте fiddle. Или хотя бы добавьте в текст вопроса - вместо фотографий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> должен быть результат из 2 полей (ID договора и его номер)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.contract_id, t3.number_contract
FROM cross_t t1
JOIN cross_t t2 ON t1.proposal_id = t2.proposal_id
JOIN plan_d t3 ON t2.contract_id = t3.contract_id
WHERE t1.contract_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t1.contract_id;
```